# return full parse object from Parse.Object.save()

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm finding myself having to write custom `PUT` routes for objects in my parse-server backend when the client needs to get the full json in the response, not just the updated properties that are returned by the Parse REST API `PUT` methods. I can achieve this in the example below, but I'd like to do it without having to have the additional `.fetch()` after the save. Without it, the save only returns the object with the properties that were updated. Is there any way to include the whole objects in the `.save()` response? I know it's available in the before/afterSave hooks.

```
function(request, response) {
  habit = Habit.createWithoutData(request.params.habitId);
  return habit.save(request.body, { sessionToken: user.getSessionToken() }).then(function(habit) {
    return habit.fetch();
  }).then(function() {
    response.status(200);
    response.json(habit._toFullJSON());
  }, function(error) {
    response.status(422);
    response.json(error);
});
```

};

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to return the saved object, because the caller has it already (by definition, it's what was just saved).  The only thing new is `createdAt` and `id`, which can be found in the result.

In the OP, the saved object is `request.body`.